# Having multiple onAuthStateChanged() calls in web app

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Using firebase, I am using onAuthStateChanged() twice each with a different callback function. I want to know if this is a correct way of using it or its only meant to be called once.

Why do I need 2 different onAuthStateChanged()?

Given a web app with a login system. Assume the user is not logged in yet so I don't want a logout button to show. That is one of the places I am using onAuthStateChanged() that checks if a user is logged in to show a logout button. Now, assume that a user again is not logged-in and is trying to access a page that is restricted to logged-in users. This is the second place I am using onAuthStateChanged(), here I display to the users that they are not signed and that they should first sign in and then after 3 seconds redirect them to the login page, and I display something else if a user is logged in. Also if a user refreshes the page whether they are signed in or not I want it to display the correct content.

TL;DR I just want to know if onAuthStateChanged() is designed to only be used once or is it okay to use it more then once.

Answer (score 0):

Use it as many times as you see fit. I don't think you're going to run into any problems.